# Android plotting points over an image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to create a simple app. The steps of the app are

1. an image should be displayed on  the screen
2. When a user selects a point on the image the xy coordinates of the selected point must be saved.
3. Then a red dot should be placed over that xy coordinates on the image.
4. It should also support pinch zoom in and zoom out. The points should be placed relatively
5. Save the image with the dot.
   Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

This is my MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();


    PointF start = new PointF();
     PointF mid = new PointF();
       float oldDist = 1f;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;
    private RelativeLayout rl_Main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rl_Main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        rl_Main.addView(new MyView(this));
    }

    class MyView extends View implements OnTouchListener{


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Point point = new Point();
        protected ImageView imageView;
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.buildDrawingCache(); 
            imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
              Bitmap b=imageView.getDrawingCache();//BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.josepg);
              canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);
              canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 1, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            dumpEvent(event);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                point.x = event.getX();
                point.y = event.getY();
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                event.getY() - start.y);
                }
                else if (mode == ZOOM) {



                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    }
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
                    }
                    break;







            }
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
              invalidate();
            return true;

        }

    }
     class Point {
            float x, y;
        }

     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }

}
```

This is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.imagemerge.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/josepg"
    android:scaleType="matrix" >
    </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

But I keep getting this error

```
07-15 10:36:20.808: W/dalvikvm(17289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415ebba8)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): Process: com.example.imagenew, PID: 17289
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagenew/com.example.imagenew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.example.imagenew.MainActivity$MyView.<init>(MainActivity.java:63)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at com.example.imagenew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-15 10:36:20.808: E/AndroidRuntime(17289):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: sounds like homework...

Comment: Did you attempt at coding it yourself? If so, please provide the code you used and why it wasn't working. If not, at least attempt before coming here.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Display the image, than log the x and y co-ordinates the next time the user taps the screen. Than draw a red circle (or use your own red dot texture) in that area.